# two tables and trying to access info from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table called users and another called tickets

The users table has

```
id
firstName
lastName
```

the tickets table has the following fields

```
id
ticket
issuedTo
fine
user (numeric id that corresponds to the id field of the user table)
status
```

I am trying to design a query where I can find all the queries that were created by a specific person

```
SELECT tickets.*, user.firstname, user.lastname FROM tickets WHERE tickets.user INNER JOIN user.id AND user.firstname="John" AND user.lastname="Doe"
```

I tried the above but didn't work so there must be something wrong with my SQL Query. Please help

I am using a Microsoft Access Database 2007.

Comment: I think that last line there is likely your problem.

Comment: LoL... Microsoft Access is terrible but thats the tool I am being forced to use.

Comment: Not knowing how to use a program as simple as Access is no reason for bad mouthing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT u.firstName, u.lastName, t.*
FROM users u INNER JOIN tickets t
    ON u.id = t.user
WHERE u.firstName = ???
  AND u.lastName = ???
```